# How to Retain Credential Exchange Records from Issuer Perspective After Completion in ACA-Py?

Tags: python, blockchain, hyperledger, aries, hyperledger-aries

I'm working with ACA-Py and have used the --preserve-exchange-records command to retain credential exchange records after completion. However, it seems that this command only retains records from the holder's perspective. The records from the issuer's perspective are being deleted upon completion of the exchange.

I have used the --preserve-exchange-records command to maintain credential exchange records, anticipating that it would retain records from both the holder and issuer perspectives after completion. However, it appears that this is not the case as the issuer's records are still being deleted. Is there a method or configuration to disable the deletion of credential exchange records for the issuer as well after the exchange is completed?

Any insights on how to preserve these records from both the holder and issuer perspectives would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!